# Generating test set in an augmented dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, caffe

I have an image retrieval task at hand. I have a dataset with not a lot of images per class, so I ended up augmenting the dataset(3 copies per image in the class) with some inspiration from the Keras [blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html). I used the `train_test_split` method in `sklearn` to split the dataset generated from the augmented dataset. Now because this is a random split, when testing there are chances that the image that is being used to test is being tested against its own augmented counterpart image, for example a flipped and slightly skewed image tested against its original. In such a case there are chances that results can be skewed? Is there a way to overcome this problem apart from just getting new data solely for testing.

Comment: You should first keep the `test` data aside, and then apply augmentation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is called "leaking", and unless the data augmentation transformations are so radical that the generated images might be similar to a real test set, then its better to split the train/test sets BEFORE doing augmentation, and only do augmentation in the train set.